# Replacing matching { braces } with do/end in Vim (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, vim

Does anyone have a plugin or macro to replace matching `{` braces `}` with `do` and `end` in Vim?  Preferably turning a single-line statement like this:

```
foo.each { |f| f.whatever }
```

into:

```
foo.each do |f|
  f.whatever
end
```

I could make a macro myself for that one case, but I'd like something that could also handle converting existing multi-line, potentially complicated blocks, like:

```
foo.each { |f|
  f.bars.each { |b| b.whatever }
  hash = { a: 123, b: 456 }
}
```

into:

```
foo.each do |f|
  f.bars.each { |b| b.whatever }
  hash = { a: 123, b: 456 }
end
```

I've looked at [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) and [rails.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails), and haven't found a way with either.

Comment: don't know much about ruby. but why your multiline example (output) only the outter `{,}` was replaced, the inner `f.bars.each{...` not?

Comment: It'd be nice to support both, but normally I wouldn't want anything but one level expanded at a time.  My scenario is I prefer in-line blocks for single statements, but often find myself wanting to add another statement or two, and I'd like to expand the block for that.  Yes, I know I should refactor it all out into a method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a Vim plugin called [Vim Blockle](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3373) that performs this function.

Once you install the plugin you put the cursor on the `{` `}` `do` or `end` and press `<Leader>b` to swap the block styles.

Comment: Thanks!  A little quirky, but this is pretty much what I was looking for.

Comment: So I looked into installing Blockle and stumbled upon a recommendation by the Blockle author to install `splitjoin` instead: https://github.com/jgdavey/vim-blockle/issues/5

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in your multi-line example, the output would be :

```
foo.each do |f|
  f.bars.each do |b| b.whatever end
  hash = { a: 123, b: 456 }
end
```

that is, the `f.bars.each{...}` should be replaced too.

if it is the goal, try this:

```
gg/each\s*{<enter>qqf{%send<esc><c-o>sdo<esc>nq200@q
```

short explanation:

```
gg               " move cursor to top
/each\s*{<enter> " search pattern we want
qq               " start recording macro to register q
f{               " move to {
%send<esc>       " move to closing {, and change it to "end", back to normal
<c-o>sdo         " back to beginning { and change it into "do"
<esc>nq          " back to normal, and go to next match, stop recording
```

then you could do for example `200@q` and check the result.

Comment: That's not quite what I'm after.  See my comment on the question.  I only want to do it for the scope of the current line.  I'll check this out and see if I can work with it, though.